# Querying where RowKey EndsWith()?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a storage table which is an index of users who follow another specific user. To do this I have set the PartitionKey to the id of the user being followed, and the RowKey to the ticks of the date they followed, as per the guide on [this post](http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2011/11/how-to-sort-azure-table-store-results-chronologically/), with the id of the following user appended to it. This is working great. Here's an example of what it looks like.

```
// FollowerIndex
PartitionKey                            RowKey
56138dad-e2db-43ac-8ffe-eac4846bf01a    2519471107153765942_31d4d0e5-2e48-489f-99fd-ead58a5fd480
56138dad-e2db-43ac-8ffe-eac4846bf01a    2519471107153765942_32fd17ec-fac2-44f8-986e-4e1fc8a05751
56138dad-e2db-43ac-8ffe-eac4846bf01a    2519471107153765942_f9816107-23ea-4ed7-a900-7465c0d10f50
f9816107-23ea-4ed7-a900-7465c0d10f50    2519471107153789651_32fd17ec-fac2-44f8-986e-4e1fc8a05751
```

My issue now is that I need to look up if one given user id is a follower of another given user id. For this I was hoping there was an `EndsWith` query I could use so that I could use a point query to increase performance as there will potentially be a lot of 'follower checks' being done. It doesn't appear this is the case.

```csharp
// request.UserId = "56138dad-e2db-43ac-8ffe-eac4846bf01a";
// request.FollowerUserId = "31d4d0e5-2e48-489f-99fd-ead58a5fd480";

var query = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equals, request.UserId),
    TableOperators.And,
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.???, request.FollowerUserId)
);
```

I am considering adding a second non-ordered index which contains the RowKey as just the id of the following user for lookups only. Is there a way to achieve what  I originally intended, or would it be better (in terms of performance and scalability) to have two indexes for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing graph relationships on Azure TableStorage there's a neat Extension called [AzureGraphStore](https://github.com/richorama/AzureStorageExtensions) and it works wonders.

It basically stores the information duplicated with different pairs of PK/RK so you can easily make queries like: Who is following X? Who does Y follow? Is A following B?

It might solve your problem completely :)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.